# Finding a pattern in a list, prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I´m trying to build a predicate pattern(List,Pattern) that takes a List formed only by a repeated pattern and the output has to be that pattern.
Some examples of the List:

```
List1=[a,b,a,b]
List2=[1,2,3,1,2,3]
List3=[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a]
```

As you can see, in each case either the list and  the pattern can have different lenghts.
And the output in each case would be:

```
Pattern1=[a,b]
Pattern2=[1,2,3]
Pattern3=[a]
```

The only way I can think about a solution is taking the first element of the List (for example, in List2 would be "1") and going through List2 until I find again a "1" and then put in Pattern everything before the second 1 ("123"), but I don´t think it is the best solution. Does anybody know an easier way to solve it? Maybe with Append/3 or Member/2? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the shortest sequence *Q* ("pattern") such that list *L* is *n* > 0 concatenations of *Q* (whereby if *n* = 1 iff *Q* = *L*), then

If you have a **verifying predicate** which verifies that *L* is indeed a concatenation of a (non necessarily) shortest *Q*:

```
multiple_concatenations(X,X).         % L = 1 * Q
multiple_concatenations(Q,L) :-       % L = N * Q (for some N >= 1, Q <> []) if
   concatenation(Q,Rest,L),           % L = Q + Rest and                                       
   multiple_concatenations(Q,Rest).   % Rest = M * Q  (for some M)
```

Where `concatenation/3` is just the sanely named `append/3` from Prolog:

```
concatenation(List1,List2,List12) :-
   append(List1,List2,List12).
```

... then you can try to find a shortest *Q* by just generating longer and longer potential _Q_s (of length going from 1 to *length(L)*) and break off at the first *Q* which passes `multiple_concatenations(Q,L,N)`:

```
shortest_q(Q,L) :-
   length(L,Length),                 % The length of L
   must_be(positive_integer,Length), % Enforce length(L) > 0; throws if not
   length(Q,N),                      % Generate a longer and longer
                                     % "list template" Q (i.e. a list with only
                                     % uninstantiated variables) on backtracking,
                                     % with N = 0,1,2,3,...
   N>0,                              % Don't want an empty template though
   (concatenation(Q,_,L)             % Q's uninstantiated members are
                                     % now instantiated; if this fails,
    ->
    (multiple_concatenations(Q,L),   % Check whether Q is acceptable
     !)                              % If yes, cut (i.e. break off at first answer)
    ;
    fail).                           % If concatenation(Q,_,L) fails, fail the
                                     % predicate: we have
                                     % gone too far (Q is longer than L)
```

Add a few plunit test cases, which are doubleplus important in the "what am I computing right now?" Prolog wonderland:

```
:- begin_tests(mq).

test(1) :-
   shortest_q(Q,[a,b,a,b]),
   assertion(Q == [a,b]).

test(2) :-
   shortest_q(Q,[1,2,3,1,2,3]),
   assertion(Q == [1,2,3]).

test(3) :-
   shortest_q(Q,[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a]),
   assertion(Q == [a]).

test(4) :-
   shortest_q(Q,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]),
   assertion(Q == [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]).

:- end_tests(mq).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: mq .... done
% All 4 tests passed
true.
```

Note however that "verification mode" accepts a sequence longer than the minimum:

```
?- shortest_q([1,2,3],[1,2,3,1,2,3]).
true.

?- shortest_q([1,2,3,1,2,3],[1,2,3,1,2,3]).
true.
```

Comment: More idiomatically, use `domain_error(non_empty_list, []).`

Comment: @false as replacement for `must_be(positive_integer,Length)` ... yes. I do not like `must_be/2` all that much, it's not very flexible (also throw only type error, which is insufficient). It's fast to type though -- if one remembers the condition atom.

Comment: Maybe `must_be/2` should be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using only `append/3` is:

```
% pattern(+List, -Pattern)

  pattern([], _).           % Any pattern repeated 0 times gives []
  pattern(L, [P|Ps]) :-     % [P|Ps] guarantees a non-empty pattern
     append([P|Ps], R, L),  % Gets a prefix of L as a possible pattern
     pattern(R, [P|Ps]),    % Checks whether prefix is indeed a pattern
     !.                     % stops when the shortest pattern is found
```

Examples:

```
?- pattern([a,b,a,b], P).
P = [a, b].

?- pattern([1,2,3,1,2,3], P).
P = [1, 2, 3].

?- pattern([a,a,a,a,a,a,a], P).
P = [a].
```